# How to use two or more different web server for an application on localhost

Tags: php, webserver

I am using XAMPP for developing my applications in PHP.

Many times I have found that a web application/site is using 2/3 different web servers like `apache/nginx/varnish` etc on live site using(info based on add-on, like wapplyzer) , I am just curious to know whether i can use these simultaneously on my local server as well.

Memcache is also somewhat that im trying to research now, will it can be also implemented at locals to check the functionality ?

Let me know how to configure it or where to apply changes if this is possible.

Not good with the system establishment part, so just excuse if something is out of line.

Comment: +1'd to undo the -1 someone put on it. This is a Q&A forum, if you don't like the question make a constructive comment instead.

Comment: @John, this is a Q&A site, not a discussion board.  Please [review the site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I expect that the downvoter did so because this question shows very little research effort and is very vague.

Comment: Well i dont know if Id try it with XAMPP... Do a real installtion of whatever tools and try it out.

Comment: @prodigitalson thanks..i think i must need to try it before asking ..but the thing is, its related with the system and sometimes installing wrong s/w may harm systems..so i thought to ask..its not a discussion thing i guess as mentioned by #charles :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish is not a web server, it is a web application accelerator. Wikipedia explains all...

> Varnish is an HTTP accelerator designed for content-heavy dynamic web
>   sites. In contrast to other HTTP accelerators, such as Squid, which
>   began life as a client-side cache, or Apache and nginx, which are
>   primarily origin servers, Varnish was designed as an HTTP accelerator.
>   Varnish is focused exclusively on HTTP, unlike other proxy servers
>   that often support FTP, SMTP and other network protocols.

As for running Apache and nginx on port 80, there are reasons why you might want to do this, but remember that both are full-fledged web servers in their own right.

Using nginx as the primary frontend webserver can increase performance even if you choose to keep Apache running on the system. One of nginx’s greatest advantages is how well it serves static content. It does so much more efficiently than Apache, and with very little cost to memory or processing. And so, it's common to find nginx handling images and other static components while leaving the dynamic "heavy lifting" to Apache.

The only reason that one would want to do this on their dev server, would be in an effort to maintain as seamless an environment from their production instance as possible.

Here's one article that explains the setup... there are many more if you use Google...

[Setting up Nginx in front of Apache2 on Ubuntu Server](http://hybridlogic.co.uk/2011/07/setting-up-nginx-in-front-of-apache2-on-ubuntu-server/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer..and yes i Googled before asking this..I just want to know whether I can install it on my localhost (Windows platform) without affecting the rest of the system..using XAMPP package for the development so can i integrate this the above mentioned accelrators or web server.

Comment: [Setup Nginx, Apache (XAMPP) On Same Server](http://www.hariadi.org/how-to/setup-nginx-apache-xampp-on-same-server/). Those instructions are for Windows, but could easily be adapted for any platform.